How to store the password for a desktop application securely
I've created an on-premises application with an installation wizard that captures the user's password. I need a secure way to store the password other than DB. If I use encryption, we'll have to save the key in the user's environment, making it vulnerable to attacks. Does Windows provide an option to store passwords securely? I have to integrate with a third party, so I can't use hashing. Even if I use hashing, how should I securely store the salt?
I've checked the encryption, but I'm concerned about securely storing the key.
